# CiviCRM Status/Connection Show 404 Not Found

Tags: error, admin

Site running on PHP 7.2.18, FPM applicated server by nginx.

I have been having an issue with my Status & Connections page loading, i can't seem to figure it out.

My Error Logs show the following:

2019/05/21 11:11:11 [error] 16655#0: *8187 "/var/www/vhosts/test.co.uk/httpdocs/civicrm/a/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 69.323.48.14, server: test.co.uk, request: "GET /civicrm/a/ HTTP/2.0", host: "test.co.uk", referrer: "https://test.co.uk/civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1"

All the other pages load correctly what i don't understand is why its looking for a index.html?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not familiar with nginx but it might be an nginx configuration - what the error says is that it's actually doing a GET for /civicrm/a/, which is getting translated by the webserver to index.html, which is actually normal. So the problem is that somewhere before that it is somehow requesting /civicrm/a/ when you visit /civicrm/a/#/status, and I'm wondering if maybe nginx config is somehow doing that.

Comment: @Demerit - Thanks for taking your time to reply to me, its a weird one I can't seem to figure it out or find any resources online to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was due to the fact i was using FPM applicated server by nginx instead of FPM applicated server by Apache.

I am not sure how to find a work around using NGINX but it is working now, thank you to everyone whos tried to help!

Thanks